# Weird code appearing when I loop over model instances in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails app I'm trying to loop over the `Submission` instances inside my `Folder` instances with Rails templating code. It works. However, it's also returning each instance in code which doesn't seem to be JSON. It's what's returned when you look up an instance in the Rails console. Here's an example:

```
#<Submission id: 112, title: nil, content: nil, created_at: "2013-10-10 23:29:39", updated_at: "2013-10-10 23:29:39", user_id: 1, folder_id: 1, parent_id: nil>
```

Here's what the code looks like for the loop:

```
<%= @folder.submissions.each do |x| %>
      <% if x.title != nil %>
        <div id="<%= x.id %>" class="submission-textual">
          <h1><%= x.title %></h1>
        </div>
      <% else %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
```

I checked my `Folder` and `Submissions` controllers but am not sure what this is. Why are these strings being rendered whenever I try and render an instance in my view? I'm still new to Ruby so that explains why I haven't seen this.

Comment: Is there any way to loop over each instance and place the title's into H1's without returning all that ERB code? Or would I have to call an API and do that in JS?

Comment: Edit:  Oh, wait. I misunderstood your question.

Comment: Yeah, I just don't want all that ERB code to be rendered into my view.

Comment: Ignore my first comment.  I thought you were asking about the ERB template itself.  I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the first line with

```
<% @folder.submissions.each do |x| %>
```

It's a small diffrerence, the equal sign after the first `%` was removed.  I think that's what's causing the unwanted rendering.

Answer (score 0):

The processing is as follows :

```
<% "ERB will evaluate this!" %>
<%= "ERB will evaluate and output this!" %>
```